# Getting `Matcher error: received value must be a promise` while testing jest with RTL in react vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

This is my useFetch.js (fetching data hook):

```
export const useFetch = (options, ref, initialvalue) => {
    const [news, setNews] = useState(initialvalue);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (ref.current) {
            const sleep = (s) =>
                new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000));
            (async () => {
                try {
                    await sleep(10);
                    const res = await axios.request(options);
                    setNews(res.data.articles);
                } catch (err) {
                    setError(err.message);
                } finally {
                    await sleep(30);
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            })();
        }

        return () => {
            ref.current = false;
        };
    }, [options, ref]);

    return {
        loading,
        news,
        error,
        setNews
    };
}
```

test code:

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useFetch } from "../hooks/useFetch.js";
import axios from "axios";


const articles = [
    {
        title:
            "ARK reduziert Anteile: Cathie Wood wirft Tesla-Aktien aus dem Depot",

        excerpt:
            "• ARK Invest verkauft Tesla-Anteile im Wert von 43,7 Millionen US-Dollar • Tesla-Aktie bleibt Top-Holding in drei ETFs • Cathie Wood sieht Tesla-Aktie falsch ...",

        _id: "e3c5e3a88c985a015b6051812198670d"
    }
];

const url = `${process.env.API_ENDPOINT}/search`;

describe("useFetch", () => {

    test("fetches successfully data from an API", async () => {
        
        const axiosGetSpy = jest
            .spyOn(axios, "request")
            .mockResolvedValueOnce({ news: articles });

        const { result } = renderHook(() =>
            useFetch(url, { current: true }, [])
        );

        expect(result.current.error).toBe(null);

        await act(async () => {
            await expect(result.current.news).resolves.toEqual(articles);
        });

        axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();

    });
});
```

Now I want to test `useFetch` hook so, I tried to test my code like this as mentioned in `test code` but this error is annoying me. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

error:

```
● useFetch › fetches successfully data from an API

    expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

    Matcher error: received value must be a promise

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"error": null, "loading": true, "news": [], "setNews": [Function bound 
dispatchSetState]}
38 |
      39 |         await act(async () => {
    > 40 |             await expect(result.current).resolves.toEqual(articles);
         |                                             ^
      41 |         });
      42 |
      43 |         axiosGetSpy.mockRestore();

      at Object.toEqual (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:229:13)
      at callback (src/__tests__/useFetch.test.js:40:45)
      at callback (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:64:24)
      at actImplementation (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2512:16)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:63:25
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/useFetch.test.js:39:12)
```

Anyone can help me with this?